# Сортировка по полученному значению в SQL запросе

Tags: join, inner, sql

Вечер добрый. Нуждаюсь в некоторой помощи. Есть запрос:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT T1.*
FROM tb_users T1 INNER JOIN 
( SELECT count(*) AS sm, referer2 FROM tb_users WHERE referer2 = 'Admin') T2
ON T1.referer = T2.referer2 WHERE referer = 'Admin'
ORDER BY T2.sm ASC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$lim) or die(mysql_error());
```

В нем не работает ORDER BY T2.sm ASC. Полученные значения выводятся в сортировке по id.

Это запрос (ну может и не он, но хотелось что бы это было так), который сортирует рефералов пользователя, в зависимости от кол-ва рефералов у этих рефералов.

В какую сторону копать не подскажете?

Comment: Я уж боюсь даже спросить, но вы хотите сказать, что с таким запросом, но без сортировки, оно что-то еще и выводит? И дабы избежать лишних доп. вопросов, закиньте примерчик на [sqlfiddle.com][1]

   [1]:http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c5d5/1

как то так)

сортируются по ID, а должны сортироваться по кол-ву ревералов

может запрос в корне не верный, но как то да работает(((

Comment: C примером, стало еще печальней. Я так и не понял, что вы хотите получить в итоге, но моя "хромая телепатия" предположила, что-то [вроде этого][1]. Сомневаюсь, что я вас правильно понял, посему уточняйте и желательно на понятном языке.

   [1]:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c5d5/28/0

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2dde5/4

хотелось бы, что бы получилось так, но без использования поля `refov`

Comment: Вот сделал как то так: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2dde5/42

Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Ваш запрос возвращает одинаковое число рефералов. Так что сортировка работает. :-)
Здесь можно посмотреть: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c5d5/30

Comment: ага, я уже это тоже нашел)